# Что важнее при обработке фотографий оперативная память или процессор?

Tags: php

уважаемые специалисты. Помогите разобраться с одним вопросом относительно обработки фотографий инструментами php.
Задача сама по себе достаточно банальная:
**На сайт загружаются фотографии в количестве 20 штук, каждая по 7 мб. Необходимо сделать из каждой из них две уменьшенные копии 960х720 и 240х180.**
Сама по себе процедура особых вопросов не вызывает и решается при помощи toolkit [AcImage](https://true-coder.ru/php/toolkit-dlya-resajza-i-kropa-izobrazhenij-na-php.html). Если речь идет об обработке единичного изображения - вопросов ноль. Все проходит гладко.
Если же мы циклом обходим 20 изображений, то скрипт не успевает обработать все картинки его выполнение сбрасывается сервером.
Сейчас используется стандартный хостинг, коих в интернете много по процессору данных нет, а вот по оперативе 128 мб.
Т.к. количество картинок предполагается большое, то рассматривается вопрос приобретения у хостинг [провайдера](https://www.activecloud.by/cloud/cloudserver/) сервера. Здесь важным становится вопрос, на что делать больший упор? Взять дополнительно 1 vCPU или 2 (4) гб оперативы.

Может ли кто-то просветить по вопросу, хватит ли для обработки указанного числа фотографий 1гб оперативной памяти и vCPU со следующими характеристиками:
*Используются процессоры Intel Xeon E5 стандартных серий. Базовая частота ядра не ниже 2,4 GHz.*

Comment: в любом случае нужно пробовать. Но кто мешает сделать поштучную обработку?

Comment: Да. Я думал сделать обработку поштучно. Но мне кажется, что провести обработку за один цикл было бы как-то правильнее. К тому же я должен пользователю показать миниатюры. Я об этом в задаче не писал, но тем не менее.

Comment: а завтра будет от одного и от другого и от третьего и все... и сдохнет даже прокачанный сервер. А так, возьмите любую штуку, которая позволяет сделать очередь (или даже в базу пишите) и потихоньку обрабатывайте. А с клиентской стороны просто проверяйте и забирайте превью.

Comment: Делайте ресайз на лету через https://imgproxy.net

Answer (score 0):

Хочу заметить что скорость выполнения задач зависит и от процессора, и от оперативной памяти, и от самой задачи. Поскольку PHP выполняется в одном потоке, вам не нужно дополнительное ядро, а также, если вы не собираетесь увеличивать количество изображений, нет смысла увеличивать размер оперативки, поэтому советую по возможности увеличить базовую частоту процессора.